# How to calculate area of quarter of circle ring in first quadrant?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

G is quarter of circle ring in frist quadrant: $G=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} x\in \mathbb R ^2 : x\geq 0, y\geq 0, 9\leq x^2+y^2\leq 49\right\} $

Calculate its area: $\int_{G}^{} \! 1 \, d(x,y) $.

Can someone help me to determine the boundaries of the integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this would be to use polar coordinates.  We have $3 \leq r \leq 7$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.  The integrand changes$^\dagger$ from $1 \ dx \ dy$ into $r \ dr \ d \theta$, so:

$$\int_G 1 \ dx \ dy = \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_3^7 r \ dr \ d\theta$$

---

$^\dagger$To elaborate, if changing to [**polar coordinates**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) is unfamiliar, the substitution is $(x, y) = f(r, \theta) = \langle r \cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta) \rangle$.  If we proceed according to [**this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables), the differential $dx \ dy$ transforms as:
$$dx \ dy = \det \left( \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial \theta} \\
     \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \theta}
  \end{array} \right] \right) dr \ d \theta = \det \left( \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     \cos(\theta) & -r \sin(\theta) \\
     \sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta)
  \end{array} \right] \right) dr \ d \theta \\ = \ r(\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)) \ dr \ d \theta \ = \fbox{$ \ r \ dr \ d \theta \ $}
$$

Comment: Clearly, there is an easier way : calculating $(49\pi-9\pi)/4$.

Comment: LOL, true @Levent.  I suppose I should've written "the easiest way to approach this *with integration*.

Answer (score 2):

Kaj Hansen addresses the simpler option. If you insist on using Cartesian coordinates, then

$$\int_G1\ \mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}y=\int_0^7\int_{\sqrt{9-x^2}}^\sqrt{49-x^2}1\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x.$$

Here you do not have to know about the [Jacobian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). However, you should be pretty good at manual integration involving roots.

**Limits on** $x$

Since we are in the first quadrant and the larger circle's $x$-intercept at $x=7$, then

$$0\le x\le7.$$

**Limits on** $y$

Solve the equations $$x^2+y^2=9, \ \ \ \ x^2+y^2=49$$

for $y$, taking into account that $y\ge0$.

Also note that $G$ is called a quarter-[annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) (more familiar than quarter-circle ring).

Comment: Glad someone added the Cartesian route (+1)!  Pedagogically, it's good to see as many methods as possible.

Comment: @KajHansen Totally agree. Then one can view the change of coordinates as a natural development, and thus proceed with the method you described. Which is, objectively speaking, the way to go.